# change system wide the connect timeout

Tags: settings, gprs

Is it possible to change the android equivalent of sun.net.client.defaultconnecttimeout?

Many applications are not working correctly over an high latency edge connection, but work with H+ or WiFi. So maybe increasing the timeout globally could help. Is that possible?